# How do I append child node in an Internet Explorer BHO extension?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho, browser-extension

I am porting a firefox extension and simply trying to append a button to an node on a web page. However nothing occurs on the page. I believe it has to do something with the conversion between HTMLDOMNode and the HTMLElement. I don't even get any errors inside console using IE dev add on.

My code:

```
public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;
        var fblike = document.getElementById("LikePluginPagelet");

        var button = document.createElement("input");
        button.setAttribute("value", "myButton");
        button.setAttribute("onClick", "doSomething()");
        ((IHTMLDOMNode)fblike).appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)button);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make fblike dynamic.

```
public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
{
    HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;
    var fblike = document.getElementById("LikePluginPagelet");

    var button = document.createElement("input");
    button.setAttribute("value", "myButton");
    button.setAttribute("onClick", "doSomething()");

    dynamic fbLike = fblike
    fbLike.appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)button);
}
```

Comment: @ redaid :How and Where to create a doSomething()?